# Access hashmap value by variable in JSP

Tags: jsp, hashmap, el

I have a hashmap, which is put to the request:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> myMap = ...
request.setAttribute("myMap", myMap);
```

In JSP I have a foreach loop

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item" varStatus="status">
   <c:out value="${item.description}"/>
   <c:out value="${myMap[item.id]}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

but `${myMap[item.id]}` does not work. How can I access hashmap's value by `item.id` variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In EL, numbers are treated as `Long`. Change your `Map` to be a `Map<Long, String>` and it'll work.

Comment: Is there a special case for `HashMap<String, some bean>`  because i tried this `${applicationscope.coursesHT[anotherbean.courseC]}` to get the description of course but it didnot work but when i use `c:set` and `c:out` it worked !! :) thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think the **id** attribute of beans is not a wrapper object (`Integer id;`). Have a look at doc page of [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

**Text from JavaDoc**

> Note: great care must be exercised if
>   mutable objects are used as map keys.
>   The behavior of a map is not specified
>   if the value of an object is changed
>   in a manner that affects equals
>   comparisons while the object is a key
>   in the map. A special case of this
>   prohibition is that it is not
>   permissible for a map to contain
>   itself as a key. While it is
>   permissible for a map to contain
>   itself as a value, extreme caution is
>   advised: the equals and hashCode
>   methods are no longer well defined on
>   a such a map.

Item.java

```
package com.me;

public class Item {
    private Integer id;
    private String description;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(Integer id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

JSP snippet

```
<%
HashMap<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
myMap.put(new Integer(1), "One");
myMap.put(new Integer(2), "Two");
myMap.put(new Integer(3), "Three");
request.setAttribute("myMap", myMap);

List<com.me.Item> list=new ArrayList<com.me.Item>();
list.add(new com.me.Item(1,"A - Desc"));
list.add(new com.me.Item(2,"B - Desc"));
list.add(new com.me.Item(3,"C - Desc"));
request.setAttribute("list", list);
%>

<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item" varStatus="status">
  <c:out value="${item.description}"/>
  <c:out value="${myMap[item.id]}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put the key-value in a map on `Java` side and access the same using `JSTL` on `JSP` page as below:

**Prior java 1.7:**

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("key","value");
```

**Java 1.7 and above:**

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key","value");
```

**JSP Snippet:**

```
<c:out value="${map['key']}"/>
```